# Lookup in other table & get the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need your help in getting the below solved.

I have data in tables
1. Extract entire dump
2. Product table

i need a view where in All the dump to display & another column looking up with the Product SKU in product table with and display as eligible. if not not eligible.

```
Select CompanyLocationId, ProductSku
From ETL_Extract,
     Product_Eligibility_List
where ETL_Extract.ProductSku = Product_Eligibility_List.ProductSku
```

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ambiguous column name 'ProductSku'.

Comment: `ProductSku` is in both tables, `ETL_Extract` and `Product_Eligibility_List`, so SQL doesn't know what do you want.

Answer (score 5):

Alias your objects, qualify your columns and stop using syntax that has been outdated for 27 years ([Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)). The error, however, is telling you the problem; `ProductSku` is ambigious as it is in both the tables `ETL_Extract` and `Product_Eligibility_List`. As a result SQL Server doesn't know which you are trying to reference in your `SELECT` (even if they do have the same value due to the `ON` clause).

Once you do all the things I initially listed, you get a query that looks like this that should provide you with the dataset you're after:

```
SELECT E.CompanyLocationId, --Guessed Alias prefix
       PEL.ProductSku
FROM ETL_Extract E
     INNER JOIN Product_Eligibility_List PEL ON E.ProductSku = PEL.ProductSku;
```